# HTML/JS/Jquery: Mimmick iOS Homescreen drag between pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, touch, gesture

I've tried a few libraries and Jquery plugins for sliding "pages" through the viewport using touch gestures, but none of them have "physics" similar to the iOS homescreen.

My goal is to assign a three-finger gesture that works on both touchscreens and touchpads that will simply move through a set of "pages" horizontally in realtime, and when the touch is released, "snap" to the currently most-visible page in the viewport. Just like the iOS homescreen.

Answer (score 0):

[SwipeView](http://cubiq.org/swipeview) will give you that. It's an infinite scroller that only loads three pages at a time. It's very quick (the company I work for uses it for one of their products.)

You'll need to customise it to work on three fingers rather than just one. If you need any help using it, I'll be glad to help =)

Comment: That's very high quality, but unfortunately it doesn't work on desktop browsers, which was part of the OP question.

Comment: Was it? I can see "touchscreens and touchpads". Swipeview works on touch events, so I'm sure any interface that will allow you to use three fingers will work with touch events in a browser. On what interfaces are you testing?

Comment: To test it with one-finger on a Desktop browser: in Chrome, you can turn on [emulate touch events](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/mobile-emulation#emulate-touch-events), which will allow you to swipe through with your mouse.